# Filter in report mixing is one of and is not one of

Tags: civireport

Is there a way in any report to have more than one Tag or Group filter? For instance it would be useful to to create a report with filter is of "this tag" and is not of "this other tag".

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the include exclude custom search to get the data you've described. If you wanted to include only those in a report then probably you could create a smart group from the results and use that in the group of choice.

Comment: hi Parvez, thanks. This is what I did: using the filter is one of for a tag and is not one of for a custom group because I had the possibility to use this filter for groups. But having the ability to mix conditions would be great. I guess there are many situations where you want to find the members of 2019 from this group but not from this other one.

Comment: So the other way to do this would be using the search builder, not sure if you tried that? Often Report/Search are interchangeable!

Comment: right Parvez, I was directly using the filter not the custom search builder which clearly deserves more interest.